# If-Then-Throw pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

In the latest edition of MSDN Magizine, there is an article [(MSDN Magizine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983479.aspx), which reference to an 'If-Then-Throw' pattern.  The idea of this pattern makes a lot of sense.  I can't seem to find any formal definition this as a pattern though.  Has anyone heard of this before?

Comment: These are also known as guards - try searching for that...

Comment: And another name is "precondition checks".

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but more an additional question. I've been around since before structured exceptions were introduced. When they were, the "rule" was that they were really only for allowing a graceful "signal" to the user of an unrecoverable error. It was spelled out very clearly that they were not to be used for anything that would resemble a business rule or anything we would consider logic signals. I've currently got a web service project I'm working on that used the pattern as you've described it. It was basically an xml over http app, with a lot of custom classes on both sides that needed to be converted to providing straight SOAP, and its been a NIGHTMARE unraveling this, as the server we're dealing with doesn't really support exposing these sorts of custom exceptions via SOAP faults...its supposed to, and its the corporate "standard", but its one of those things where the vendor starts their answer with "Our interpretation of the spec....", bleech.

So getting to my additional question, when did this mutation take place? Is it really considered to be a good way of doing things? I'm not sure if its the same on all platforms, but in JavaLand, under the influence of almost universal acceptance of Spring there is a major backlash against checked exceptions, so in that case there isn't really necessarily a "contract", and you'll have unexplained and unexpected exceptions bubbling up all over the place.

I know error codes are considered quaint and old fashioned, but they certainly seem to be working better for the projects I've been working on, but as always, I look forward to being educated otherwise.

Thanks.